# No apps appearing - unfortunately settings has stopped. com.android has stopped

Tags: applications

no apps appear at all.
I cant access menu

theres only settings app
play store

ive tried hard reset

error messages of

com.android has stopped
settings has stopped

im lost

Comment: Can you please reformulate?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my samsung ace last week. Unfortunately disabling and uninstalling  those 'pesky' apps caused my phone to lose the ability to msg although I could make+recieve.calls this isn't very convenient on a unlimited text account. After the reset was done the phone went crazy and was blinking off and on, different colored lights too. Then some veŕy small print in upper right corner came up addressing the developer. Koodo people basically said phone was toast. Had to get a new one. Like I said though, it was an Ace so that particular model was crappy to begin with :/

Comment: This doesn't seem to directly address the issue elise was having. This seems like an unrelated story of your own similar experience, and one without a solution. Can you please clarify the comment to explain what aspects are the same as elise's problem, and what troubleshooting was done before it was determined it was "toast?"